# How to get rows where a value is indivisible by 0.01 - potential issues with floating point arithmetic

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, precision

I have a pandas Series with float values, like below:

```
s = pd.Series({0: 899.0,
  1: 899.0,
  2: 1099.0,
  3: 279.29998779296875,
  4: 2598.833251953125,
  5: 499.1666564941406,
  6: 1709.050048828125,
  7: 279.29998779296875,
  8: 999.0,
  9: 1498.9949951171875}, name="var")
```

I'd love to get indices of all values that are indivisible by 0.01, so I tried to define `mask = (100 * s % 1) > 0`, which works fairly well with provided example series:

```
s[mask] 
3     279.299988
4    2598.833252
5     499.166656
6    1709.050049
7     279.299988
9    1498.994995
Name: var, dtype: float64

s[~mask]
0     899.0
1     899.0
2    1099.0
8     999.0
Name: var, dtype: float64
```

However, `s` provided here is just a sample of much bigger dataset and when I'm doing the same on the original Series, the value of `mask` for `1709.050049` is `False`, which indicates that those `0049` digits are just floating point representation issue for number `1709.05`, which was extracted as such when I created `s` from my original data with `pd.Series.to_dict()` method. Therefore, I wonder if my way of masking the numbers indivisible by `0.01` (`mask = (100 * s % 1) > 0`) is correct. If it isn't, what's going wrong with that solution and how can we mask the values correctly?

Comment: That looks like a complicated way of avoiding a problem that should be solved differently... What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Can you explain what "indivisable by .01" mean?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille To get numbers indivisible by 0.01 is actually my ultimate goal. Those numbers represents prices and any price which is not a multiplicity of `0.01` is suspicious in a way that maybe some discount was applied or something like that.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov indivisible means that it can't be divided by `0.01`, i.e. it's not a multiplicity of `0.01`

Comment: The difficulty is that the quantity 0.01 cannot be represented accurately in floating point because it is not a multiple of powers of 2. Try multiplying by 100 and converting the result to `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: @BoarGules I belive that won't work either, as for example when I multiply `326.78` by 100 I get `32677.999999999996`

Comment: I said, after multiplying, *convert to `decimal.Decimal*`. That let's you specify the precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve what you want with [np.isclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html), by setting an `rtol` param:

```
s = pd.Series({
    0: 898.999998,
    1: 899.0,
    2: 1099.0,
    3: 279.29998779296875,
    4: 2598.833251953125,
    5: 499.1666564941406,
    6: 1709.050048828125,
    7: 279.29998779296875,
    8: 999.0,
    9: 1498.9949951171875,
    10: 326.78}
    , name="var")

tolerance = 1e-12
mask = np.isclose(s, s.round(2),rtol = tolerance)
s[mask]
1      899.00
2     1099.00
8      999.00
10     326.78
Name: var, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is a very neat idea (+1), thanks for that! However, as in one of my previous comments when I multiply `326.78` by `100` I get `32677.999999999996` and the modulo operator returns `0.999999999996362` which is close to `1`, not `0`.